# Tarski Monster group with prime $3$ or $5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any Tarski Monster Groups for the prime $3$ or $5$? I know that there is no 
Tarski Monster Groups with prime $2$, but I don't know for the prime $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Are the Tarski Monsters not only known to exist for very large primes?

Comment: What i know is that for primes >1003 such group always exist. But this does not mean that for prime 3 or 5, such group does not exist.

Comment: Could you give a reference for that existence? I only remember having seen it for much larger primes than that.

Comment: S I Adyan and I G Lysënok, ON GROUPS ALL OF WHOSE PROPER SUBGROUPS ARE FINITE CYCLIC, Mathematics of the USSR-Izvestiya   Volume 39   Number 2

Comment: Finitely generated groups of exponents 2,3,4 and 6 have been proved finite. Exponent 5 (together with lots of other small exponents) is unknown.

Answer (score 17):

There does not exist a Tarski monster for $p=3$, while I am unsure about the $p=5$ case. However, I understand that it is an open problem to prove that every two-generated group of exponent $5$ is finite (if such groups were finite then there would be no Tarski monster for $p=5$).

For $p=3$, this is because any finitely-generated group of exponent three is finite (this is a "left to the reader" exercise at the start of Chapter 6, using the start of Chapter 4, of Ol'shanskii's book *Geometry of Defining Relations in Groups*). Indeed, the free Burnside group of rank $m$ and exponent three has order $3^{m+{m \choose 2} + {m\choose 3}}$ (see [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112357/groups-of-exponent-4/112363)).

To see that every finitely generated group $G$ of exponent three is finite, begin by using $a^3=1$, $b^3=1$, $(ab)^3=1$ and $(a^{-1}b)^3=1$ to get that $a(bab^{-1})=(bab^{-1})a$ (this is Figure 25, p113, of Ol'shanskii's book). Thus, $a$ commutes with its conjugates, and so $a$ lies in some abelian normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, $N=\langle a^b: b\in G\rangle$. As $a$ is arbitrary, every element lies in an abelian normal subgroup of $G$. This implies that $G$ is finite, as take $a$ to be a generator and look at $G_1=G/N$. Then $G_1$ is generated by fewer elements than $G=G_0$, and $G_2=G_1/N_1$ is generated by fewer elements than $G_1$, etc. If $G_1$ is infinite then this process will obtain after finitely many steps a finite group, $G_n$ say, such that $G_{n-1}$ is infinite. We then have $G_0\rightarrow G_1\rightarrow G_2\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow G_n$. We shall prove that $G_{n-1}$ is finite, a contradiction, and so $G=G_1$ is finite. As $G_n$ is finite, $N_{n-1}$ has finite index in $G_{n-1}$. As $G_{n-1}$ is finitely generated, and finite index subgroups of finitely generated groups are finitely generated, we have that $N_{n-1}$ is finitely generated. It is also abelian of exponent three, and so $N_{n-1}$ is finite. As $N_{n-1}$ is a finite finite index subgroup of $G_{n-1}$, we have that $G_{n-1}$ is finite, and the proof is complete. (This ending is sloppy. Any ideas for a neater way?)

I have given up trying to find decent references for the $p=5$ case. Perhaps this would be a good MathOverflow question. Mark Sapir frequents there, and he should know this (my "looking for a reference" consisted of trawling through his papers...).